# typescript Promise - persist change in mapped array of objects

Tags: arrays, ionic-framework, promise, capacitor

I am trying to replace the value (file paths) of the key/value entries in an array of objects upon the if-condition, that a file/ or files exist in the file directory Documents ( ios capacitor ionic ); else, just return the array unchanged.

Arrays

```
   const currentItems = this.data;
   const filenames = [val, val, ...];
```

// for loop

```
   for (let filename of filenames) {
```

// capacitor FileSystem API; promise

```
    Plugins.Filesystem.stat({
      path:filename+'.jpeg',
      directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents
    }).then((result) => {
```

// return path to file in Documents directory ( simplified)

```
      const result.uri = this.imagepath;
```

// map array

```
      const newItems = this.currentItems.map(e => {
```

// if entries match set the value for key 'linethree'

```
        if (e.lineone === filename) {
          return {
            ...e,
            linethree: this.imagepath
          }
        }
```

// else, return e unchanged

```
        else
          return { ...e,}
      });

    }).catch( reason => {
      console.error( 'onRejected : ' + reason );
    })

}
```

The problem:

on every iteration - filename of filenames - the original array is mapped again - with its original values; thus each iteration overwrites the change from the previous iteration.

How can it be achieved that the value entry at key 'linethree' for each match - e.lineone === filename - persists ?

Desired replacement:

```
const filenames = ["uncle"];
```

[{"lineone":"nagybácsi","linetwo":"uncle","linethree":"./assets/imgs/logo.png"}]

[{"lineone":"nagybácsi","linetwo":"uncle","linethree":"_capacitor_/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D95D4DEF-A933-43F1-8507-4258475E1414/Documents/nagybácsi.jpeg"}]

Comment: Hi, can you provide example with demo data? What you have and what you need as result. Thanks.

Comment: The user can take a photo and that photo is then linked to a string. Say: "rose" - user takes picture of a rose. Then I display string rose and picture of rose in an ionic template. If no picture is found in file directory, a dummy.jpeg is shown. My need is to generate the path to the picture just taken and saved to filedirectory and replace the dummy path in the array .Usind capacitor fileSystem API.

Comment: I mean to provide an basic example, not real data... Like const filenames = [somedata] const result = [myresult] ?

Comment: Use this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qn0pvrcf/ update it as i said in previous post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand well you need something like this:

Solution with `Array#Filter`, `Array#Some` and `Array#Map`

```js
const wantedImagePath = '_capacitor_/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D95D4DEF-A933-43F1-8507-4258475E1414/Documents/nagybácsi.jpeg';

const fileNames = ["uncle"];
const someData = [
{
  "lineone":"ikertestvérek; ikrek",
  "linetwo":"twins",
  "linethree":"./assets/imgs/logo.png"
},
{
  "lineone":"nagybácsi",
  "linetwo":"uncle",
  "linethree":"./assets/imgs/logo.png"
},
{
  "lineone":"nőtlen (man)",
  "linetwo":"unmarried",
  "linethree":"./assets/imgs/logo.png"
},
{
  "lineone": "bar",
  "linetwo": "foo",
  "linethree": "./some/demo/path/logo.png"
}
];

const modifed = someData.filter(x => fileNames.some(y => y === x.linetwo)).map(z => ({ ...z, linethree: wantedImagePath }));
console.log(modifed)
```

Update:

Solution if you want to keep current data and modify matched:

```js
const wantedImagePath = '_capacitor_/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D95D4DEF-A933-43F1-8507-4258475E1414/Documents/nagybácsi.jpeg';

const fileNames = ["uncle"];
const someData = [
{
  "lineone":"ikertestvérek; ikrek",
  "linetwo":"twins",
  "linethree":"./assets/imgs/logo.png"
},
{
  "lineone":"nagybácsi",
  "linetwo":"uncle",
  "linethree":"./assets/imgs/logo.png"
},
{
  "lineone":"nőtlen (man)",
  "linetwo":"unmarried",
  "linethree":"./assets/imgs/logo.png"
},
{
  "lineone": "bar",
  "linetwo": "foo",
  "linethree": "./some/demo/path/logo.png"
}
];

const modified = someData.map(x => {
  let match = fileNames.find(y => x.linetwo === y);
  return match !== undefined ? ({ ...x, linethree: wantedImagePath }) : x;
});

console.log(modified)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I will try to understand the logic. Will it work with more than one file name: e.g. picture for uncle, twins but not for  unmarried ? In other words: with a loop for ( filename of filenames ).

Comment: Thank you, that is already very close to perfect. My last need: if I do "for ( filename of fileNames )"  - uncle, aunt - so that linethree changes in more than one entry, is that working without overwriting the 'uncle' change. I think that it should work with this code, just asking.

Comment: Sorry but can't answer because i need more information and more code... One suggestion, try to use `MAP`, `FILTER`, `REDUCE`, `SOME`, `EVERY`.... methods and combine it together instead `FOR LOOP`.... This is a more better way without mutating data and less code. Also try to understand my solution if you have any questions be free to ask. Good luck and upvote. Thanks.